# Too High CPU Footprint of OpenCV Text Overlay on FHD Video Stream

Tags: c++, opencv, video-processing, video-capture, preview

I want to display a FHD live-stream (25 fps) and overlay some (changing) text. For this I essentially use the code below.

Basically it is

1. Load frame
2. (`cv::putText` skipped here)
3. Display frame if it's a multiple of `delay`

but the code is super super slow compared to e.g. `mpv` and consumes way to much cpu-time (`cv::useOptimized() == true`).

So far `delay` is my inconvenient fiddle-parameter to somehow make it feasible.

- `delay == 1` results in **180 % CPU usage** (full frame-rate)
- `delay == 5`  results in 80 % CPU usage

But `delay == 5` or 5 fps is really sluggish and actually still too much cpu load.

> How can I make this code faster or otherwise better or otherwise solve the task (I'm not bound to opencv)?

**P.s.** Without `cv::imshow` the CPU usage is less than 30 %, regardless of `delay`.

```cpp
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

// process ever delayth frame
#define delay 5

Display* disp = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
Screen*  scrn = DefaultScreenOfDisplay(disp);
int screen_height = scrn->height;
int screen_width  = scrn->width;

int main(int argc, char** argv){

  cv::VideoCapture cap("rtsp://url");
  cv::Mat frame;

  if (cap.isOpened())
    cap.read(frame);

  cv::namedWindow(  "PREVIEW", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL );
  cv::resizeWindow( "PREVIEW", screen_width, screen_height );

  int framecounter = 0;
  while (true){

    if (cap.isOpened()){

      cap.read(frame);
      framecounter += 1;

      // Display only delay'th frame
      if (framecounter % delay == 0){
        /*
         * cv::putText
         */
        framecounter = 0;
        cv::imshow("PREVIEW", frame);
      }

    }
    cv::waitKey(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you compiling your code with optimization enabled (aka "release build") or are you testing a unoptimized build?

Comment: [Here](https://pastebin.com/ePrYmjdj) is the full output of `cv::getBuildInformation()` for the `opencv` itself. For this code, I didn't specify anything but `-O3`.

Comment: how much cpu is used without putText active? What kind of machine are you using? Is it better if you increase cv::waitKey to 5, 10 or 20?

Comment: @Micka Enlarging `waitKey` did nothing on the cpu load as seen by `htop` except that from some point on the fetching of the frames fails.

Comment: what kind of machine are you using? Maybe capturing and cpu rendering is too expensive for your hardware? Can you try `cv::namedWindow("PREVIEW", cv::WINDOW_OPENGL);` if you have a graphics chip?

Comment: @Micka It's a i3-8100T, so it has a Intel UHD 630 and the resizing of a FHD image should not be an issue at all. I compiled it now with OpenGL support (Debian version hasn't) and `cv::WINDOW_OPENGL` is even faster than `cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` (55 % CPU compared to 65 %) but does not work together with `cv::WINDOW_KEEPRATIO`, so it squeezes the image. Fitting a 16:9 video to a 16:10 screen is kind of acceptable atm but I have another stream with 4:3 ratio that would look awkward.

Comment: thx for testing, I tried to find out what happens with cv::resizeWindow, compared to `cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE`, but haven't been successful.

Comment: @Micka Thank you for the effort! If you find out anything or have other ideas regarding the question, please let me know!

Comment: @Micka `cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` [disables resizing completely](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#gabf7d2c5625bc59ac130287f925557ac3) (*"size is constrainted by the image displayed"*) whereas `cv::WINDOW_OPENGL` offloads the complete rendering (with resizing) to the GPU. I wasn't aware that resizing is such an effort for the CPU (as done with `cv::WINDOW_NORMAL`). I adapted my answer below accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now found out about [`valgrind`](https://www.valgrind.org/) (repository) and [`gprof2dot`](https://github.com/jrfonseca/gprof2dot) (`pip3 install --user gprof2dot`):

```
valgrind --tool=callgrind /path/to/my/binary    # Produced file callgrind.out.157532
gprof2dot --format=callgrind --output=out.dot callgrind.out.157532
dot -Tpdf out.dot -o graph.pdf
```

That produced a wonderful graph saying that **over 60 % evaporates** on `cvResize`.
And indeed, when I comment out `cv::resizeWindow`, the cpu usage lowers from 180 % to ~ 60 %.

Since the screen has a resolution of 1920 x 1200 and the stream 1920 x 1080, it essentially did nothing but burning CPU cycles.

So far, this is still fragile. As soon as I switch it to full-screen mode and back, the cpu load goes back to 180 %.

To fix this, it turned out that I can either disable resizing completely with `cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` ...

```cpp
cv::namedWindow( "PREVIEW", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
```

... or -- as [Micka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2393191/micka) suggested -- on OpenCV versions compiled with OpenGL support (`-DWITH_OPENGL=ON`, my Debian repository version was not), use ...

```cpp
    cv::namedWindow( "PREVIEW", cv::WINDOW_OPENGL );
```

... to offload the rendering to the GPU, what turns out to be even faster together with resizing (55 % CPU compared to 65 % for me).
It just [does not seem](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/9911) to work together with `cv::WINDOW_KEEPRATIO`.*

Furthermore, it turns out that `cv:UMat` can be used as a drop-in replacement for `cv:Mat` which additionally boosts the performance (as seen by `ps -e -o pcpu,args`):

[image: Mat-UMat performance profile]]

---

#### Appendix

[*] So we have to manually scale it and take care of the aspect ratio.

```
float screen_aspratio = (float) screen_width / screen_height;
float image_aspratio  = (float) image_width  / image_height;

if ( image_aspratio >= screen_aspratio ) { // width limited, center window vertically
  cv::resizeWindow("PREVIEW", screen_width, screen_width / image_aspratio );
  cv::moveWindow(  "PREVIEW", 0, (screen_height - image_height) / 2 );
}
else { // height limited, center window horizontally
  cv::resizeWindow("PREVIEW", screen_height * image_aspratio, screen_height );
  cv::moveWindow(  "PREVIEW", (screen_width - image_width) / 2, 0 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing that pops is you're creating a new window and resizing it every time you want to display something.

move these lines

```
cv::namedWindow( "PREVIEW", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL );
cv::resizeWindow( "PREVIEW", screen_width, screen_height );
```

to before your `while(true)` and see it that solves this

Comment: Oh, sure! Thank you! I updated the code above. It gave me 1 or 2 % but it's not really changing the outcome.

Comment: did you check the CPU usage you're getting without displaying anything (remove the `cv::imshow()`? just to see what you're starting with, to make sure that the overhead comes from opencv and not from the streaming part

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk we're trying to figure out what is the cause. we don't know, if you have something to suggest, please do and help.

Comment: Without `cv::imshow()` I'm down to 29 % (0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4) for both `delay == 5` and `delay == 1` (CPU utilization of the process (CPU, utilization, of, the, threads, in %) -- as listed by htop). So, the rest is `opencv`.

Comment: Possibly off-topic: Interestingly, on the full fps stream I have 11 threads (a 4-core i3 gen. 8) where 4 threads are again around 4 %, 4 at 0 % and 3 do the heavy lifting. Is it the way it's supposed to be?