# OpenCV, can't release CAP_OPENCV_MJPEG VideoWriter for long records

Tags: c++, opencv, avi

Hi stackoverflow community,
I recently had a problem with the performance of the opencv VideoWriter ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65342914/why-opencv-videowriter-is-so-slow)), and I am now using cv::CAP_OPENCV_MJPEG as a backend instead of cv::CAP_FFMPEG.
Now I am running in another issue, so my code looks like this:

```
cv::VideoWriter videoWriter(path, cv::CAP_OPENCV_MJPEG, fourcc, fps, *size);
videoWriter.set(cv::VIDEOWRITER_PROP_QUALITY, 100);

int id = metaDataWriter.insertNow(path);

while (this->isRunning) {

    while (!this->stackFrames.empty()) {

        cv:Mat m = this->stackFrames.pop();

        videoWriter << m;
    }

}

videoWriter.release();
```

This loop runs in a separate thread and "isRunning" will be switched from outside. There is a stack with cv::Mat (stackFrames) which is filled by another thread that captures the images by a video capture card. This works fine, but if the file size is too big, several GB, I get the following error when the videoWriter.release() is called:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
> what():  OpenCV(4.4.0) /home/michael-gary/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/container_avi.cpp:27: error: (-211:One of the arguments' values is out of range) Failed to write AVI file: chunk size is out of bounds in function 'safe_int_cast'

I tried to change the video container from .avi to .mkv, .mp4, .mpg but none of them is working, it does not even create the file. Only .avi is working, but fails by the release.
For now I will try to write multiple files, so I don't run in this problem, but I would like to face the problem itself.
Open for any suggestions

BR Michael

Answer (score 1):

AVI files are practically *limited* in size.

when you force it to use OPENCV_MJPEG, it will only use OpenCV's own writing methods, which can only do AVI and MJPEG.

if you need a different container, you have to use a different backend, such as FFMPEG. you can still have MJPG for a codec (fourcc).